# how to use regex with vega

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vegas-viz

I am new to vega lite / vega.

I'm trying to write a regex query for a java log error as following with vega tree layout.
A field 'message' contains :

```
[Poolthread] com.xxxx.content.core-bundle com.xxxxx.content.model.impl.RegisterTypeInternal(3179)] The activate method has thrown an exception (com.xxxxx.content.model.exception.ModelException: ModelException: {Code}-LCC-REP-FCT-002, {Message}-Access denied)
com.xxxx.content.model.exception.ModelException: ModelException: {Code}-LCC-REP-FCT-002, {Message}-Access denied
    at com.xxxxx.content.repository.utils.ExceptionUtil.getException(ExceptionUtil.java:52)
    at com.xxxxx.content.repository.utils.ExceptionUtil.getException(ExceptionUtil.java:171)
```

i'm use this regex which gets an exception word before the character : (like as ModelException ) but i don't how use this regex in vega  . i tested this regex on the site regex101.com and it works fine.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?=:)
```

Thank for your help

Comment: I do not fully understand your problem, but if you can use expressions, there is documentation for regex: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#regexp-functions

Comment: The regexp functions return only boolean values. This function is used with the split and replace function.
I can't use to define group, find, matchers like in java programming.
I just wanted it to return the value found .
otherwise if you have examples of the regexp functioon with vega. i want to .

Comment: @hostar
example with this regex
https://regex101.com/r/Cl07Fb/1
i would that regex return value of the first group 1 : ModelException .